# Unknown realm [myRealm]. null returned for key: isUserAuthenticated

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight 6.1 and trying to check if the user is authenticated or not:

I have a Realm defined in `server/conf/authenticationConfig.xml`

```
<realm name="myRealm" loginModule="myLoginModule">
<className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
<parameter name="login-function" value="authentication.onAuthRequired" />
<parameter name="logout-function" value="authentication.onLogout" />
</realm>
```

and its login module

```
<loginModule name="myLoginModule">
<className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
</loginModule>
```

and after logging in, or even before that, when I try to check if the user is authenticated or not using

```
WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("myRealm")
```

I have the following response

```
 Unknown realm [myRealm]. null returned for key: isUserAuthenticated
```

Anyone have an idea about that ?
Is there something wrong with my Realm definition ?
Is there a better way to check if a user is authenticated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you first call to `WL.Client.updateUserInfo();`?

From the documentation:

> updateUserInfo(options)
>
> This method refreshes user data after an exception. Use this method
>   when the application receives an exception after calling the
>   invokeProcedure() method. The method refreshes the data for the
>   following methods:
>
> WL.Client.getUserName(realm)
>   WL.Client.getLoginName(realm)
>   WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm)
>
> After such an exception, you can verify the user authentication status
>   by calling this function first, and then the isUserAuthenticated()
>   method.
>
> Parameters: options - Optional. A standard options object.

Comment: it seems to be working after calling updateUserInfo()