# How to Check whether the Client is logged in for Particular Realm or not in worklight 6.2 using Client Side WL API?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

1.) I have Tried with `WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm)` but it was not working.

2.) So i tired with refreshing the relams by `WL.Client.updateUserInfo (options)` in function `function wlCommonInit()`and tried with refreshing outside of the `wlCommonInit()` function.

3.) I tried to retrieve the logged in Users details from Client side by these also:

```
a ) WL.Client.getUserName(realm)
b ) WL.Client.getLoginName(realm)
c ) WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm)
```

But not able to get Boolean value as `True` for `WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm)` and active details of User logged in for particular realm.

Would be please let me know the proper details or methods to get the Active Users details without using `WL.Server.getActiveUser(realm)` from server side.

I just wanted how to do in client side.

Regards,

Sheikh Mohammed Shamnoon

=====Comment

I am Able to get the User which i have set by using "WL.Server.setActiveUser(Realm, userIdentity);".I don't have any problem in getting the logged in user which is set in server end,I am retrieving for different adapter by using "
WL.Server.getActiveUser("SingleStepAuthRealm");", That way it works by passing isAuthenticated as another object while returning authRequired == false,I want in Client side  i am not able to retrieve value for WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated() == "true" even if user is logged in i tried refreshing realms by using "WL.Client.updateUserInfo (options)" even i tried with delay after refreshing "WL.Client.updateUserInfo (options)" then called "WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated()" but still not working for me..

Comment: What you getting? Error or something else. Can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770854/ibm-worklight-wl-client-getusername-fails-to-retrieve-useridentity-immediately.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Please edit your question to elaborate. What errors do you get?

Comment: I wana get the details of logged in Client after authentication for the particular realm. on a client side I am not getting WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm) is as true, Even if the Client for that realm is authenticated ......I mean after logging in if i call WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm) the output will be false instead of true....

Comment: When you are invoking WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(), in the authentication flow? If it is so then can you give some delay once you receive authsuccess:false. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770854/ibm-worklight-wl-client-getusername-fails-to-retrieve-useridentity-immediately

Comment: See @AndrewFerrier my Comment in Main Question:::: above because of less character's allowed i couldn't explain here ...And thanks for showing interest on solving this problem..:-) please help to find out solution...

Comment: WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("SingleStepAuthRealm");
Unknown realm [SingleStepAuthRealm]. null returned for key: isUserAuthenticated worklight.js:4871WL.Logger.__log worklight.js:4871PUBLIC_API.(anonymous function) worklight.js:5229getUserInfoValue worklight.js:7105isUserAuthenticated worklight.js:8205(anonymous function) VM293:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn VM82:730InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap VM82:669InjectedScript.evaluate VM82:581
false

Comment: I hope this will answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593729/ibm-worklight-6-1-unknown-realm-myrealm-null-returned-for-key-isuserauthen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Call to WL.Client.updateUserInfo();?
2. WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm)

Similar issue addressed here.

[unkonwn realm[myRealm]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593729/ibm-worklight-6-1-unknown-realm-myrealm-null-returned-for-key-isuserauthen)

Comment: Can you please tel me how to use because i was refreshing by using  WL.Client.updateUserInfo() in function wlCommonInit(). Then checking for WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm) its not working ..what do you mean by "This method refreshes user data after an exception. Use this method when the application receives an exception after calling the invokeProcedure() method. The method refreshes the data for the following methods:" Even i have refereed that previously but still it was not working i might be using in wrong place i guess ...

Comment: Can you try the following. singleStepAuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response){
 var authRequired = response.responseJSON.authRequired;
 if (authRequired == true){
  .... 
 } else if (authRequired == false){
  ....
  singleStepAuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
  WL.Client.updateUserInfo();
  WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(realm);
 }
};